# extended Acsii to Ascii conversion in C

Tags: utf-8, ascii, buffer-overflow, endianness, extended-ascii

We want to simulate a buffer overflow attack by sending a payload through sending a payload in HTTP head.
We have the correct length of the payload which just overwrites the return address of the function. However, the return address when specified in hex is incorrectly converted to 7 bit ascii when sent through cURL.

(ASCII for /0xe2 is â, so we send this special character)
for eg, i want the ret address to be 0xbffffce2, so in little endian notation e2 is sent first and gets converted to c3. that gives us the incorrect address

curl -H 'If-Modified-Since: 000000000000000 /Very big payload/ AA**â**\r\n' 'localhost:8094'

any ideas?

If this doesnt work due to ASCII/Extended ASCII problem, then how could we possibly include shell code in the payload ! Can we send the shellcode in ASCII by any chance

I believe this problem is not tool-dependent (tried plain telnet as well)